# Comparing floats in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`Floats` and `Doubles` represent approximate numeric data values. For this reason we can't compare them on the `where` cause like we do with other data types.

Is there any drawback if I compare double and floats like this `CAST(column_name as CHAR) = CAST(@value as CHAR)`

Is there a reason the MySQL website recommends using `ABS(a - b) <= some value`

Comment: Generally, if you want to do this kind of comparison, then you probably shouldn't be using FLOATS or DOUBLES

Comment: @Strawberry I know that decimals are preferred. I just have to use floats/doubles.

Comment: @MATH000 not sure what website resource you are using, but I am not aware of an `ABS` function that takes two parameters in MySQL. You would typically do `ABS(a - b) <= some value`. As for the reason behind using that equation, `some value` is usually called a "tolerance value". Think of it as an acceptable level of difference in the comparison. If it was 0.001, comparing two floats will return true should the difference be within one thousandth.

Comment: @ Jonathon Ogden I apologize, I meant: ABS(a-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this simple example can summarise the problem with CHAR...

```
SELECT CAST(2 AS CHAR) > CAST(11 AS CHAR);
+------------------------------------+
| CAST(2 AS CHAR) > CAST(11 AS CHAR) |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.31 sec)
```

mysql>